# Chrome / Opera blink painting issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I found an inexplicable issue with my pages painting and then "unpainting" in blink browsers. After the page renders, most of the viewport, but not all, goes blank and ceases to paint. Here is the screen as it should be after I've forced it to paint:

[image]

And here is the screen as it looks after the page renders and "unpaints" itself:

[image]

The behavior is consistent and the same regions are unpainted every time. It's not a very demanding application in terms of visual animation.

Tech info: Angular, angular-ui-router, CSS animations for everything.

Any insight into why blink renders and then blanks out most of the page is very much appreciated.

Comment: Opera is not a webkit browser? Or do you mean some iOS app?

Comment: I mis-spoke and said webkit where I should have said blink. I've edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: I suggest reporting this issue at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en and also at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the`ng-cloak` directive in your body tag for example.

More information about `ng-cloak` on this link: [ngCloak docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Hope my answer will fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but on login page.

Also I have use AngularJS and ui-router, and I think that is caused by redirection inside onStateChangeStart event.

[Dicussion on github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/178)

i have discovered, that is, probably blink engine issue and then find your question here, because if you turn on rerender page option in google chrome devtool rendering tab this problem will be resolved.

So! Today i've tried to change css properties and find that removing

```
position: fixed;
```

from the main container css resolve the problem. Maybe you have some of this properties in your styles. Try to remove or replace them.

Best regards!